# installing other python version in virtual environnement ubuntu

Tags: python, virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04

I'm currently running tests on a macbook 2009 turned to ubuntu mate 18.04.
My question is very simple:

- this distro comes with python3.6.9
- I would like to install python3.10.10 without having to install it on the gloval system, but only in a virtual environnement because when I first tried it ended up in blocking update manager, notifier and ubuntu software store!!
  Practically, if I use wget https.... to download the latest python version while my venv is activated, where does this new version of python will be installed and when will it be useable? Only when venv is activated?
  Thank you so much for your help.
  De716

Comment: Why even bother with a 5 year old Linux distribution? Upgrade to the latest and you'll have a new Python included. That said, `wget` does not install anything. You'll have to add more details on how you create your virtual environment and how you deal with the downloaded Python. Did you check the documentation for your virtual environment tool? See also [ask].

Comment: This will help to install other Python versions on Ubuntu: https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa -- What you should not do is try to install another Python 3.6 on top of the one you already have, that would break things for sure.

Comment: You can not have a Python that is only in the virtual environment, it is always globally installed. -- Anyway, you probably should seek help on https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/ because here we help with code and you do not have code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone and thank you for this quick answer.
Reason why I'm working with ubuntu mate 18.04 is that on my macbook 2009, using 22.04 was making the computer really slow. Switching to 18.04 has solved the problem. And I'm using my macbook to prepare my moving to my imac 5K 2020 , this time with the latest ubuntu distro.

Here is the procedure I first used to install python 3.10:

created a virtual environment using : python -m venv myvenv

Once this done , activated myenv and used url to source code to download via wget command.Before that I downloaded libssl-dev openssl etc... that are necessary to installing python.

I then followed procedure with :
./configure --enable-optimizations
cd Python-3.10
make
make install

After that I can find and make use of python3.10 in /usr/local/bin, wether myenv is activated or not.
Thus my previous question about python version being available globally or only in myenv.

I did a lot of researches and found both answers about the possibility to install a new version only in a virtual environment, that's why I came to you.

The latest recommendation I got was to choose a directory outside the system ones, for example in /opt and compile/install a new version of python sa os to "separate" it from the python system version.

Thank you again

Regards.
De716